# $\langle dN_p(v_1),dN_p(v_2)\rangle = \lambda(p) \langle v_1,v_2\rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry

I don't know how to solve this problem from Do Carmo, Differential Geometry, p. 216:

Let $S$ be a regular surface without umbilical pints. Prove that S is a minimal surface if and only if the Gauss map $N: S\rightarrow S^2$ satisfies

$\langle dN_p(v_1),dN_p(v_2)\rangle = \lambda(p) \langle v_1,v_2\rangle$

for all $p \in S$ and all $v_1,v_2 \in T_pS$, where $\lambda(p) \neq 0 $ is a number which depends only on $p$.

It's important for me... Thank you!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuc?

Comment: I don't know... $v_1$ and $v_2$ seem to be eigenvectors of $dN_p=-W_p$, but the text says they can be any vectors from $T_pS$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the characteristic polynomial of the linear map $dN_p$ and what is the definition of a minimal surface? And then recall the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

Comment: thanks for the hint, its really important for me. the characteristic polynom of $W$ ($=-dN_p$) is $ \kappa^2 - 2H \kappa +K$ which is equal to $\kappa = H +- \sqrt[H^2-K]$. $H=0$ because $S$ is a minimal surface. so we get: $\kappa = +- \sqrt[-K]$. So $K$ (Gaussian curvature) has to be negative. I dont know how to go on.

Comment: So $dN_p^2 = -K(p)I$. Remember that the linear map $dN_p$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand the conclusion, why is $dN_p^2=-K I$?

Comment: Did you look up Cayley-Hamilton?

Comment: ok now i understand this conclusion. how can i use that it is self adjoint now?

Comment: @JadonD87: I hoped you'd figure this out yourself. If $T$ is self-adjoint, what is $\langle T^2 v_1,v_2\rangle$?

Comment: thanks and sorry, is $\langle T^2v_1,v_2\rangle = \langle Tv_1,Tv_2 \rangle$ right? then i would understand this way. but how works the other direction. if the equation is satisfied, why does S have to be a minimial surface?

Comment: This is again linear algebra. If $\langle Sv_1,v_2\rangle =0$ for all $v_1,v_2$, then $S=0$.

Comment: Why is S a minimal surface if $S=0$?

Comment: I chose $S$ for a different linear map. Try $S=dN_p^2 - \lambda I$.

Comment: thanks, but i still dont understand how i can show that the equation in my question implies that $H=0$

Comment: You need to figure *something* out here. I've pretty much done everything for you. Come on!

Comment: sorry, i feel really stupid, i dont know